# Laravel Target class [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController] does not exist

Tags: laravel

I was making a small blog site, but got this error. Is there anyone who can help? Currently, my homepage page that I defined in view is not working.
My homepage.blade.php page, by the way, inside the front folder is homepage.blade.

my web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Front\HomeController;


Route::get('/',"HomeController@index");


-----------------------------------------------

here is my controller

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Front;
use App\Http\Controllers\Front\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Category;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $data['categories']=Category::inRandomOrder()->get();
 
       return view('front.layouts.homepage',$data);
     }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code not image

Comment: sorry, i will share the code next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like below code

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error, Class "App\Http\Controllers\Front\Category" not found

Comment: You have to use `use App\Models\Category` in the header section in `HomeController`

Comment: I have a homepage.blade.php page in View. But I got such error.   "View [front.homepage] not found"

Comment: You have to use `return view('front. homepage',compact('data'))`

Comment: I defined in Controller but it didn't work.  :(

Comment: Which didn't work? I can't understand. Your folder structure should be `resources\views\front`

Comment: View [front.homepage] not found.     Now this error

Comment: @dilankaratas, Happy to help you and accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do like this -

```
Route::get('/','Front\HomeController@index');
```

because You have directory like `App\Http\Controllers\Front\HomeController`.
and you can't call without calling the exact path.
hope, It helps.

Comment: I tried this, I typed the full folder path, but it was didnt work.

Comment: plz update the queston, with code , in picture its truly blurr

Comment: plz attach controller also, so that we can see.

Comment: I fixed my question and removed the pictures.

Comment: dude, you can't call the controller in the same file where you are working in the same controller

Comment: ı fixed all problems, thanks everybody:))

Comment: if anyone's answer was correct , plz mark accepted on the icon below down arrow key

Comment: I'm new here and I don't know some things. Thanks for telling me.